# My future builder is not working, snapshot data is empty

Tags: flutter

My future builder is not working snapshot data is empty.
In other future builder cases my code works correctly.
My api gets correct data too.
this is my run terminal:

[image]

```
  static Future<List<User>> getUser() async {
    var url = '${Constants.BASE_NO_TOKEN_DOMAIN}api?action=user_profile&token=${Constants.USER_TOKEN}';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final body = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return body['data'].map<User>(User.fromJson).toList();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userFuture = getUser();
    getToken();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(245, 248, 250, 1),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 25, right: 16),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12))),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
              height: 120,
              child: FutureBuilder<List<User>>(
                future: userFuture,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    final user = snapshot.data!;
                    return buildUser(user);
                  } else {
                    print(snapshot.data);
                    print(snapshot.error);
                    return Text("No widget to build");
                  }
                },
              ) // FutureBuilder
            ),  //Container
```

Comment: `print(body['data'])` what you see on logs? - the error says it's a `Map`, not `List` as you think

Comment: you didn´t add the await keyword in your initState() function when call to getUser(), it can be the problem, because you are not waiting for the api fetch when calling the function getUser()

Comment: my body['data'] work correct I see what gives me api: {name: Женя, surname: Тян, father_name: null, full_name: Женя Тян, phone: 7777777777, email: null, role_name: Пациент, is_online: true, avatar: {100: https://health.6zeros.org/images/no-avatar.png, 400: https://health.6zeros.org/images/no-avatar.png, full: https://health.6zeros.org/images/no-avatar.png}}

Comment: could you add User class too?

Comment: this is my User class:
`` class User {
  final String fullName;
  final String avatar;
  final int phone;

  const User ({
    required this.fullName,
    required this.avatar,
    required this.phone,

  });
  static User fromJson(json) => User(
    fullName: json['full_name'],
    avatar: json['avatar_100'],
    phone: json['phone'],
  );
} ```

Comment: so this is a `Map` object, you cannot call `map` method with one parameter on it

Comment: if i delete ``` map``` from my code i got this error: 
I/flutter (10262): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<User>>'

Comment: sorry for my stupidity, but i got new error: Error: The argument type 'Future<User>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<List<User>>?'.

Comment: @st4tic you need to change you FutureBuilder type too. check out my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have a Map not list so you need to change your `getUser` to this:

```
static Future<User> getUser() async {//<--- change this
    var url = '${Constants.BASE_NO_TOKEN_DOMAIN}api?action=user_profile&token=${Constants.USER_TOKEN}';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final body = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return User.fromJson(body['data']);//<--- change this
  }
```

second in your model class you are parsing `avatar` wrong, try this:

```
class User {
  final String fullName;
  final String avatar;
  final int phone;
  const User({
    required this.fullName,
    required this.avatar,
    required this.phone,
  });
  static User fromJson(json) => User(
        fullName: json['full_name'],
        avatar: json['avatar']['100'], // <--- change this
        phone: json['phone'],
      );
}
```

also change your `FutureBuilder` to this:

```
FutureBuilder<User>(
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your api returns a single user and not a list of them. If you still need a list you could wrap it in one. So maybe try this:

```
  static Future<List<User>> getUser() async {
    var url = '${Constants.BASE_NO_TOKEN_DOMAIN}api?action=user_profile&token=${Constants.USER_TOKEN}';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final body = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return [User.fromJson(body['data'])];
  }
```

EDIT:

From you other comments I could conclude that the parsing of the user goes wrong. You do

```
avatar: json['avatar_100']
```

but there is no field named that. You should try

```
avatar: json['avatar']['100']
```

Comment: yes, my api return a single user, unfortunately it doesn't work, snapshot data is still null, i got this error message: 
I/flutter (10262): type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'